# View displays entire SQL query instead of displaying result set

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two linq queries in my controller that are both designed to return a string.  However, my view displays the entire SQL query generated from the Linq query.

Model:

```
public class DummyClass
{
    public string myMessage { get; set; }
    public string myInitials { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult EmployeeSignature()
{
    using (MessageInfo db = new MessageInfo())
    {
        var message = db.SiteMessage_MyPay
                        .Where(x => x.active)
                        .Select(x => x.msgText).ToString();

        using (DocumentReviewed database = new DocumentReviewed())
        {
            var document = database.Document_Reviewed
                                   .Where(x => x.FileNumber == "whatever")
                                   .Select(x => x.Initials).ToString();

            var model = new DummyClass()
                {
                    myMessage = message,
                    myInitials = document
                };

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyPayTC.Models.DummyClass
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EmployeeSignature";
}

@Model.myInitials

@Model.myMessage
```

Website displays:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Initials] AS [Initials] 
FROM [dbo].[Document_Reviewed] AS [Extent1] 
WHERE '105057' = [Extent1].[FileNumber]
```

Comment: `ToString()` on your query is almost certainly not what you intended.  If you only expect one result consider `SingleOrDefault()`.  If there may be more than one result and you only want the first, try `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I had tried FirstOrDefault().ToString() and it did not work.  SingleOrDefault() works by itself.

Comment: It should be FirstOrDefault() and not FirstOrDefault().ToString()

Comment: You'll quickly find that there are few valid reasons to use `.ToString()`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `.ToString( )`, you should use `.FirstOrDefault()`, `ToList()`, etc like this:

```
var message = db.SiteMessage_MyPay
                .Where(x => x.active)
                .Select(x => x.msgText).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or, if you want to retrieve some columns, you can use `ToArray()` or `ToList()`.